# How to persist user connection and reconnect in spring social?

Tags: spring-social

Is it possible to persists a spring-social connection and reconnect programmatically?

I'm working on an app that tweets on behalf of its users (currently based largely on the quick start example of Spring Social).

The problem is that it works only as long as the app runs, if it's restarted the users have to sign in again. What should be persisted with the users in order to be able to reconnect when the app starts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that is covered in Section 2.3 of the documentation:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/serviceprovider.html#service-providers-persisting-connections